# Store unmasked InputMask value in Formik and Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, input-mask

Alright, so I have this implementation of Input Mask over a custom styled implementation of Material UI's text field, inside a Formik form:

```
<InputMask
                        mask="999-99-9999"
                        maskChar="X"
                        value={values.ssn}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        className={classNames(
                          styles.inputField,
                          styles.override
                        )}
                      >
                        {() => (
                          <LNTextField
                            name="ssn"
                            label="Social Security Number"
                            error={touched.ssn && errors.ssn ? true : false}
                            helperText={
                              touched.ssn && errors.ssn ? "* " + errors.ssn : ""
                            }
                            type="text"
                          />
                        )}
                      </InputMask>
```

The problem now is that in `values.ssn` the value is stored with the mask, with the hyphens and all, I would instead like it to be stored as a number/string with no spaces/masks, how would I go about that?

Comment: can you check this sample? https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57191028-formiksubmit-58kig

Comment: What's in the sample? it seems you're storing with the mask normally like me, I'd like to store without the mask, just a string of numbers.

Comment: on submit, I'm removing `-` with regex `value.ssn.replace(/[-]/g, "")`. sorry that fiddle was not updated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Kiran LM 's comment codesample, this was acheived by adding this instead of the existing `onChange`, aswell as destructuring `setFieldValue` from Formik

```
                      onChange={e => {
                        const value =
                          e.target.value
                            .replace(/-/g, "")
                            .replace(/X/g, "") || "";
                        setFieldValue("ssn", value);
                      }}
```

Many thanks to them.

Comment: You don't need to replace `X` , because it won't come in value, so `.replace(/X/g, "")` is no longer needed.

Comment: It was coming in value during the typing process, hence causing the length to always equal 9, and not trigerring my "SSN needs to be 9 digits" error.